# Unexpected bash autocompletion behavior within a symbolic link loop

Tags: bash, autocomplete, symlink

I have the following directory structure:

```
base/
  dir/
    subdir/
    link -> ../dir
```

Now if I cd to dir/link and type:

```
cd ../subd[tab]
```

I get:

```
cd ../subdir[space]
```

1. I would understand if autocomplete fails (because it would canonize the path and look into base/ and not dir/).
2. I would also understand if it autocompletes to `cd ../subdir/` with the ending / (because it would interpret `..` as `go up one level` and search into dir/).

But I do not understand the actual behaviour that is somewhere between the two. Ideally I would like bash to behave like 2. (autocomplete to cd ../subdir/). I am using fedora 14, bash version 4.1.7(1). Any idea how to accomplish this ?

Comment: Googling for "bash autocomplete symlink to directory" finds: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14337/why-is-bash-completion-of-a-symlink-different-than-a-directory http://superuser.com/questions/155167/tab-completion-with-directories-links http://superuser.com/questions/271626/bash-autocomplete-on-symlink-to-directory-complete-to-whole-directory-including

Comment: First link is about find, not bash autocompletion.

Second link is about autocompletion to a symlink. This is not my case as subdir is a regular directory. Also I guess I have mark-symlinked-directories set to on already as typing `cd li[tab]` autocompletes to `cd link/`

None of these links tell me how to complete to `cd ../subdir/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging the source code a bit, it looks like this is a bit complicated. The actual problem is a mix between bash allowing symlinks inside the working directory (see pwd -L and pwd -P) and readline not able to determine the type of a match if it is not in a physical directory

In  [readline/complete.c:1694](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/readline.git/tree/complete.c#n1694)

```
s = (nontrivial_match && rl_completion_mark_symlink_dirs == 0)
? LSTAT (filename, &finfo)
: stat (filename, &finfo);
```

stat() fails since ../ is understood as relative to the physical path and not the logical path. readline fails to determine this is a directory and therefore does not append the final '/'.
A very similar problem is described [here](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=650787)

So I guess I can live with the existing behaviour for now...

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: The program with which you can customize auto-completion is called `complete`.

You can find some good basic examples here: *[More on Using the Bash Complete Command](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/more-using-bash-complete-command)*

Using function and script names as per the above link, here is a script which appends the `/` to a symbolic link to a directory... It is just a rough sample, but it shows it can be done (I haven't tried it with the `cd` builtin...

Associate the function `_mycomplete_` with executable `myfoo`

```
complete -F _mycomplete_ myfoo
```

The function to go in `~/.bashrc`

```
function _mycomplete_()
{
    local cmd="${1##*/}"
    local word=${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}
    local line=${COMP_LINE}
    local xpat='!*.foo'

    COMPREPLY=($(compgen -f -X "$xpat" -- "${word}"))
    if ((${#COMPREPLY[@]}==1)) ;then
       [[ -h $COMPREPLY ]] && COMPREPLY="$COMPREPLY/"
    fi
}
```

---

Original answer:

At the command-line, the main indicator of a auto-expansion to a symbolic link is shown on the last line of the following table, ie. a name expands but without the final `/`.

```
 on pressing TAB                                         on pressing TAB (again)  
  what happens?              meaning                        what happens?
===================      =======================     ==================================== 
Nothing is appended  1=> Multiple sub-dirs exist  => A list of possibilities is presented
                     2=> No sub-directory exists  => Nothing is appended (again)

Expands to end in /   => A uniquely matching dir  => ...as per first column (repeat)
Expands text only     => Current name is a link   => Expands to end in /
```

In your example, if you have already primed the command-line to the full name, ie. `cd  link` then the indicator is not obvious.  Also you won't know it is a symbolic link via the list of possibilities.

To be able to `cd` to  the link's target, you can use `cd -P link`, or `set -P; cd link`

Comment: Where do you get the table from ? Is it documented in bash manual or did you get it from experience ? About the lcd() command, I do not really need this. What I want is autocomplete to put the ending '/'.

Comment: Also a strange thing I just noticed is that both `cd ../dir` and `cd ../subdir` work ! Looks strange...

Comment: I seems that what you need it `complete` ... I haven't used it before, but it certainly allows for customization.... I've added a link ..

Comment: Problem is I want to customize the default `cd` command. So using complete would force me to completely override the default completion just for my particular case. This could work but I do not like it so much. And it still does not explain why the default completion is behaving this way...

Comment: My impression, from reading that linked page, is that it is most likely a simple case of it being the deault behaviour for `cd` (the page refers to a definition file (couldn't find it on my system though)... eg. I like it (and probably others do too). I like it because it offers a way to know that it **is** a symbolic link...

Comment: I guess you're right by saying it 'works as designed' But `subdir` **is not** a symlink so I still find the behaviour a bit strange.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the exact same problem in Ubuntu. Autocompletion was working like in your example #2, but started working as you describe at some point. I purged and reinstalled the package bash-completion, and now everything seems back to normal. Do not uninstall bash! Only bash-autocompletion.

Edit

look at this:

https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=113158

Comment: I doubt this is the same problem as I do not have the bash-completion installed. Also the problem I describe is very specific to symlink and the internal readline completion