# bash tab completion filter out options

Tags: bash

I would like to make tab completion in bash a bit more intelligent.

Let's say I have a folder with a src file .lisp, and a compiled version of that file .fasl. I would like to type vi filename [tab tab], and the .lisp autocompletes as the only option. That is, it's not likely that I want vim to open a compiled binary, so don't have it in the list of autocomplete options to cycle through.

Is there a way that I can keep a flat list of extensions that autocomplete ignores, or somehow customize it for vim, so that autocomplete ignores only particular file extensions when a bash command starts with vi ...

Any ideas are appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/22854848/1888983 and http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/108423/54030

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bash `complete` command seems to  be what you want.

Here is a *Linux Journal* link to ['complete' command video](http://www.linuxjournal.com/node/1008402). and here is the follow-up page [More on Using the Bash Complete Command](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/more-using-bash-complete-command)

The links explain it quite well, and here is a related SO Question/Answer: [Bash autocompletion across a symbolic link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10120274/bash-autocompletion-across-a-symbolic-link/10122937#10122937)

Comment: Thanks! This worked quite well. However, I could not use the -f version in my bashrc, b/c it overwrote the -F version in /opt/local/etc/bash_completion. So I just added the .dx64fsl compiled binary extension to the bash_completion file (tweaked the -F version). If Macports updates it, I'll notice.

Answer (score 13):

From `man bash`:

> ### FIGNORE
>
> A colon-separated list of suffixes  to  ignore  when  performing
>                 filename completion.  A filename whose suffix matches one of the entries in `FIGNORE` is excluded  from  the
>                 list of matched filenames.  A sample value is `".o:~"` (Quoting is
>                 needed when assigning a value to this variable,  which  contains
>                 tildes).

So, for your example this can be set in your `.bashrc` file with

```sh
FIGNORE=".o:~:.fasl"
```

or, if you want to keep any other site-wide settings:

```sh
FIGNORE=".o:~:.fasl:$FIGNORE"
```

Comment: For users like me who are a bit basic on all this stuff, can you explain how we set that variable (or is it a file?). Thank you.

Comment: Ok I found out myself: I put export FIGNORE=".aux:.log:.dvi:.pdf:" in my .bashrc file. Btw I am doing this for my latex work, so that when I type vim mylatexf<TAB> it will complete to mylatexfile.tex rather than just show me the list of possible completions like mylatexfile.aux, mylatexfile.dvi etc.

Comment: The complete command is nice, but this is the real answer to the question.